# Rails 5: JQuery inside $(document).ready does not fire from page to page, only on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Edit: I found the issue to my answer here:

[Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

---

As the title says, I have some JQuery at the bottom of the `application.js` file inside my Rails 5 app. I've noticed it won't fire if I'm traveling from page to page. It will however, work if I just reload the page I'm on.

Just to be perfectly clear, this is my `application.js` file:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
... Rest of file.
//= require_tree .

$( document ).ready(function() {
  alert('test');
});
```

I won't get an alert at all if I'm just clicking page to page within my app. Again, the `alert` will only fire if I reload the page I'm currently on.

Any help with this would be wonderful.

Comment: when you're going from page to page, are you just changing the view using AJAX or is the page reloaded every time you go to a new page?

Comment: No ajax, it's just standard.

As I'm doing more research, I'm starting to see it might be a turbolinks issue.

Comment: Look up turbolinks - the document ready event will no longer fire.  There are various workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I started to do more research, I found out it was a turbolinks issue.

I was able to reference this answer:

[Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

changing,

`$( document ).ready(function() {...`

to

`$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {...`

fixed all my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try changing `$(document).ready()` to `$(window).load()`.